# error occurs when preview or loading data from azure Databricks

Tags: powerbi, azure-databricks

I connected to databricks successfully by entering 'Server Hostname' and 'HTTP Path', and the hive tables are successfully shown as well.

But when I trying to click a table for previewing the data, I got below error.

```
DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '0' error message: 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
              at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServerErrors$.runningQueryError(HiveThriftServerErrors.scala:53)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$thriftserver$SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$execute(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:435)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$2$$anon$3.$anonfun$run$2(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:257)
              at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ThriftLocalProperties.withLocalProperties(ThriftLocalProperties.scala:123)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.ThriftLocalProperties.withLocalProperties$(ThriftLocalProperties.scala:48)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.withLocalProperties(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:52)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$2$$anon$3.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:235)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$2$$anon$3.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:220)
              at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
              at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
              at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$2.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:269)
              at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
              at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.SimpleKeyProvider.getStorageAccountKey(SimpleKeyProvider.java:51)
              at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AbfsConfiguration.getStorageAccountKey(AbfsConfiguration.java:577)
              at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.initializeClient(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:1832)
              at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.<init>(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:224)
              at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.initialize(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:142)
              at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
              at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:537)
              at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
              at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaLog$.apply(DeltaLog.scala:626)
              at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaLog$.forTable(DeltaLog.scala:527)
              at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaTableV2.deltaLog$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:80)
              at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaTableV2.deltaLog(DeltaTableV2.scala:80)
              at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaTableV2.$anonfun$snapshot$3(DeltaTableV2.scala:108)
              at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
              at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaTableV2.snapshot$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:108)
              at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaTableV2.snapshot(DeltaTableV2.scala:97)
              at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaTableV2.tableSchema$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:113)
              at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaTableV2.tableSchema(DeltaTableV2.scala:111)
              at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaTableV2.schema(DeltaTableV2.scala:115)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Relation$.create(DataSourceV2Relation.scala:186)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.$anonfun$createRelation$2(Analyzer.scala:1576)
              at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.$anonfun$createRelation$1(Analyzer.scala:1535)
              at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$record(Analyzer.scala:1752)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$createRelation(Analyzer.scala:1535)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anon$3.$anonfun$submit$6(Analyzer.scala:1701)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$4(SQLExecution.scala:448)
              at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$3(SQLExecution.scala:448)
              at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$2(SQLExecution.scala:447)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withOptimisticTransaction(SQLExecution.scala:465)
              at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1(SQLExecution.scala:446)
              at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
              at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.$anonfun$run$1(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
              at
```

Can any expert please help advise how to resolve the error in powerBI?

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).

Comment: Not really sure, but can you please go through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/partners/bi/power-bi) and see if it helps... Also pls provide a little more information on how you authenticated ? manually or using partner connect, AAD or using a personal access token, someone might be able to figure it out. All the best...